# is there a way to create a dynamic form in flutter

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, for-loop, flutter-layout

Does anyone have know how to implement something close to the below image in flutter? I have tried (code below) but am having some issues.
[image: questionpageview]
The idea is to create a ui where users can create questions and answers for that question and select the correct answer which would be uploaded to the backend database,
I started by creating an empty list which adds new text from when you tap the add questions button which is hooked to a for loop as shown below.

```dart
class _QuestionsSectionState extends State<QuestionsSection> {
  final questionsField = <String>[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (var i = 0; i < questionsField.length; i++)
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    helperText: 'Question',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) { 
                  },
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  questionsField.removeAt(i);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        const SizedBox(height: 12),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            questionsField.add('');
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: const Text('+ add question Field'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The problem with that is when I remove a `textfield` it pops from the last one and not the index that should be popped so I used a map of string instead which looks like the below code.

```dart
class _QuestionsSectionState extends State<QuestionsSection> {
  final questionsField = <Map<String, String>>[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (var i = 0; i < questionsField.length; i++)
          Row(
            key: ValueKey(questionsField[i].keys.first),
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    helperText: 'Question',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    final key = questionsField[i].keys.first;
                    questionsField[i][key] = value;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  questionsField.removeAt(i);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        const SizedBox(height: 12),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            questionsField.add({const Uuid().v1(): ''});
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: const Text('+ add Field'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This solves the problem of adding multiple questions and deleting each specific question, but I can't still figure out how to create the same process for answers of the question which can be removed without a problem.
The model is below.

```dart
class QuestionValues {
  QuestionValues({
    required this.question,
    required this.answer,
    required this.correctAnswer,
  });
  Map<String, String> question;
  List<Map<String, String>> answer;
  String correctAnswer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I already figured it out. A long time ago.maybe I can put the way I did it later. You can check My app Griiled on playstore. Used the same logic. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbum.griiled.griiled.dev

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

add a question in textfield

onclick put this question in a questions list and display at runtime and clearing controller for new question.

Same you can do with answers.

add answer to answers list and use same textfield for next answer.

like this

[image]

[image]